# Why do you have to pad syscalls on OSX?

Tags: macos, assembly

For example, I want to call `void exit(int exit_code)`:

```
main:
  push 42    ; Push the return value
  push 0     ; Pad the value before calling the interrupt 
  mov eax, 1 ; exit syscall
  int 80h    ; invoke
  ret
```

Why do I need to pad the arguments for this to work properly?

Comment: OSX keeps the stack aligned to 16-byte boundaries, afaik... I suspect that's the reason.

Comment: Ah, that pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the extra push was inherited from the BSD syscall calling convention.

In it, the `int 80h` instruction originally resided in separate function which was called after pushing the syscall arguments. It means that there was an extra, implicit push caused by the `call` instruction and the syscall handler expected and skipped it. Since you do not use a wrapper, you have to push another padding value.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html